# Random number adder using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, random

I need to create a program that enters in a start and end value of a range of numbers.

Comment: why do you swap the start and end values if `startval<endval`? Shouldn't the startval be less than the endval? I think you want to flip that comparator to a `startval>endval`

Comment: where is the code that gave you trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
randnum = (int)((endval - startval) * Math.random()) + startval
```